# python dual for loops does not provide the expected results

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, nlp

I am new to python . i am trying to run the below code but the results are not as expected:

```
c = [0,1,2,3,4]
clus = [c0,c1,c2,c3,c4] #each element in the list is a dataframe
for i in c:
    Movie = data.Title[data.labels == i]
    for j in clus:
        vect = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english',max_features=5)
        cv_fit = vect.fit_transform(j).toarray()
        key_features = vect.get_feature_names()
    print("Cluster",i,"details:")
    print('-'*80)
    print("Key Features:", key_features)
    print("Movies in the cluster:")
    print(Movie)
    print("Movies in the cluster:",i)
    print(' ')
    print(' ')
```

Expected Output:

```
Cluster 0 details:
--------------------
Key features: ['water', 'on the', 'her', 'while', 'she']
Movies in this cluster:
One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest, The Sound of Music, Star Wars, Chinatown, The Bridge on the River Kwai, Apocalypse Now, Jaws, The Good, the Bad and the Ugly, Butch Cassidy and the Sundance Kid
========================================
Cluster 1 details:
--------------------
Key features: ['her', 'she', 'about', 'to her', 'that she']
Movies in this cluster:
Gone with the Wind, The Wizard of Oz, Titanic, Psycho, Sunset Blvd., Vertigo
========================================

and so on ....
```

But my Current Output is:

```
Cluster 0 details:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Key Features: ['water', 'on the', 'her', 'while', 'she']
Movies in the cluster:
0     One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest
1     The Sound of Music
3     Star Wars
4     Chinatown
6    The Bridge on the River Kwai
93    Apocalypse Now
94    Jaws
95    The Good
97    the Bad and the Ugly
99    Butch Cassidy and the Sundance Kid
Name: Title, Length: 67, dtype: object
 

Cluster 1 details:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Key Features: ['water', 'on the', 'her', 'while', 'she']
Movies in the cluster:
7     Gone with the Wind
56    The Wizard of Oz
85    Titanic
89    Psycho
92    Sunset Blvd
100   Vertigo
Name: Title, dtype: object
 
and so on ...
```

Key features remains the same for all the clusters. What should i adjust in my code so that my
key features also changes for different clusters.

```
data.head(2) looks like the below:

       Title       |          Synopsis                |    Labels |
     --------------------------------------------------------------
0    |The Godfather|Guests are gathered last summer...|       0   |
1    |Raging Bull  |The film opens in 1964 ....       |       1
```

CountVectorizer is an algorithmn that we use in natural language processing (NLP)

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
```

I need the cluster number like (0,1,2,3,4) then followed by
key features in each cluster. Each cluster is a dataframe which is a subset of the "data". c0 was taken from the data whereever the labels are "0"
similarly it was done for all the c0,c1,c2,c3,c4.

Each cluster will have a unique key features since the input is different for each cluster. but my code prints the c0 key features for all the clusters which is incorrect .

11th line of the code has some problem because of which it prints the same key feature results which it got for cluster0 instead of printing the result of cluster1

Comment: Please also post a *copy-pastable* `data`, `CountVectorizer`, `vect`, or any other missing parts that will make this code a [mre].

Comment: Without your data, this is practically impossible to diagnose; that’s why you must always include a [mre] in your question , which you haven’t. How would you solve a problem where someone says ‘my code doesn’t work’ but doesn’t include enough information to debug the code? Read [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for the nested loop.

```
c = [0,1,2,3,4]
clus = [c0,c1,c2,c3,c4] #each element in the list is a dataframe
for i in c:
    Movie = data.Title[data.labels == i]
    cluster = clus[i]
    vect = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english',max_features=5)
    cv_fit = vect.fit_transform(cluster).toarray()
    key_features = vect.get_feature_names()
    print("Cluster",i,"details:")
    print('-'*80)
    print("Key Features:", key_features)
    print("Movies in the cluster:")
    print(Movie)
    print("Movies in the cluster:",i)
    print(' ')
    print(' ')
```